# Rewrite POST requests to different host in NGINX

Tags: node.js, rest, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a React App with express. I am running Nginx as a reverse proxy. The App makes POST requests a relative url of `/api/rest/2/issue/`. How do I rewrite the url to use a different host eg `https://example.com/api/rest/2/issue/` for POST requests.

The normal GET requests must go to the standard port 80.

I have tried this in my vhost:

```
location /rest/api/2/issue {
   proxy_pass https://example.com/rest/api/2/issue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just simply need

```
location /rest/ {
   proxy_pass https://example.com/rest/;
}
```